# Google Cloud - Private service connection for CloudSQL using Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to automate the deployment of a system using deployment manager. In essence, it's comprised of:

- One compute instance running a proxy server
- A second compute instance running the app itself (private IP only)
- A CloudSQL instance hosting the database (MySQL)

In the existing environments they have, the database is configured with a private IP address, and private service access in the network so that the compute instance can acccess the DB by its private IP.

I've managed to get the 2 instances running, and the CloudSQL instance, but I"m struggling to get the private IP set up on the SQL instance. I've got the following:

```
    - name: database
      type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
      properties:
        backendType: SECOND_GEN
        instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
        region: {{ properties["region"] }}
        databaseVersion: {{ properties["dbType"] }}
        settings:
          tier: db-n1-standard-1
          dataDiskSizeGb: 10
          dataDiskType: PD_SSD
          storageAutoResize: true
          replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS
          locationPreference:
            zone: {{ properties['zone']}}
          ipConfiguration:
            privateNetwork: {{ properties["network"] }}
```

However, when I try to build this, I receive the error:

> Failed to create subnetwork. Please create Service Networking
>   connection with service 'servicenetworking.googleapis.com' from
>   consumer project '' network '' again

I've tried to dig through the documentation to find how to create this connection using Deployment Manager, but I'm at a loss! I got as far as creating a private address range for peering:

```
    - name: google-managed-services-<network_name>
      type: compute.beta.globalAddress
      properties:
        network: $(ref.<network_name>.selfLink)
        purpose: VPC_PEERING
        addressType: INTERNAL
        prefixLength: 16
```

and this appears to create the reservation for private service links correctly, but I can't find the final piece of the puzzle, the actual peer connection to Google's network. The documentation suggests the CLI call I need is:

```
> gcloud services vpc-peerings connect 
    --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com 
    --ranges=[RESERVED_RANGE_NAME] 
    --network=[VPC_NETWORK] 
    --project=[PROJECT_ID]
```

but as far as I can tell, Deployment Manager doesn't support this API.

Has anyone had success with automating this sort of setup before? Pointers to relevant documentation that I might have missed are of course welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [servicenetworking.googleapis.com](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-networking/reference/rest/v1/services.connections/create) is not currently supported by Deployment Manager nor is it a supported [GCP-type](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types) so this can't be done through DM for now. I recommend creating a feature request for it since it's a relatively new API.

Comment: To configure a private network using `gcloud` _before_ the first SQL instance is created with that network, see also [Configuring private services access for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#configure-access) (official docs).

Answer (score -1):

below config works for me, after setting  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#configure-access

```
  ipConfiguration:
    privateNetwork: "internal"
    ipv4Enabled: false
    authorizedNetworks: null
```